# Camel SMPP reconnection strategy

Tags: apache-camel, jsmpp

I have an application with 2 routes that are in charge of sending sms messages.

We noticed that sometimes, the connection is lost (or seems to be lost). In those case, Camel  tries to reconnect to the SMSC and what is happening is that in some cases instead of having 2 connections to the smsc we have 4 connections opened to the smsc.

The problem at smsc level we have a limit of connections available.

What could you advise to avoid that kind of behaviour ?
Is there a way to make sure that a new connection is not done until the initial connection is closed.

Comment: What Camel version do you use?

Comment: Camel version is: 2.10.3